# Adding a custom control to a nib file

Tags: ios, checkbox

I just discovered that there is no checkbox control in ios. I have found several resources that explain how a custom checkbox could be made. My question is how can I place a custom checkbox control on to a content view . Should I just put a view control in that specific position and then programmatically add the custom control to the view. I wanted to know what is the most common way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Use a UIButton and change is background image on click.

Comment: Why don't you use iOS way of `UISwitch` or `UISegmentedControl` for checkbox and radio button behavior?

Comment: Insert generic view in your nib and in identity inspector change its class to your custom control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are mostly for OSX. 
On iOS equivalents you can use `UISwitch`, or use a `UIButton` and set its state (highlighted, selected, ..) depending on the user selection.

If you absolutely want a checkbox, here is a guide showing how to do it. Seems nice, but I haven't tried it.
http://x-code-tutorials.com/2013/04/09/ios-xcode-checkbox-uibutton/